# Hierarchical kendo grid child grid not binding data

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to implement hierarchical kendo grid, Parent grid is binding the data but child grid is not binding the data and its not even hitting the data source action method. Please find my code below. Can any one please let me know what is wrong with my code.
[image]

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BankruptcyMilestoneViewModel>()
                                .Name("BankruptcyMileStoneManagement")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.BankruptcyMilestoneName);

                                })
                                .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
                                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                                .Sortable()
                                .Filterable()
                                .Selectable()
                                .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(600))
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(o => o.BankruptcyMilestoneTrackingId);
                                    model.Field(o => o.BankruptcyMilestoneName).Editable(false);
                                })
                               .Read(read => read.Action("GetBankruptcyMilestones", "BankruptcyMilestone").Data("milestoneData"))
                               .ServerOperation(false)
                               .Events(s => s.Sync("sync_handler"))
                                             )

                                    )


<script id="client-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<BankruptcyMilestoneDetailsViewModel>
    ()
    .Name("grid_#=BankruptcyMilestoneName#")
    .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "max-height:200px;" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.BankruptcyMilestoneDescription).Width(110);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CompletedDate).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(o => o.DueDate);

    })
    .DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetBankruptcyMilestoneDetails", "BankruptcyMilestone", new { milestoneParams = "#=BankruptcyMilestoneName#" }))
    )
    .ToClientTemplate()
    )

</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Does your controller method `GetBankruptcyMilestoneDetails` has the parameter `milestoneParams` in its signature?